# NHibernate collection not loading with data, but data is inserted into database

Tags: nhibernate, one-to-many, mappings

Not sure what I am doing incorrectly here with NHibernate. I have two mapping files mapped to two tables. I can insert data through the mapping into the database, but calling the below code returns 0, even though I can see a child row populated in the table with the correct foreign key. Is this a lazy loading issue? Thanks.

```
var result = session.Get<AnnualReport>(annualReport.ReportID);
Assert.AreEqual(result.MonthlyReports.Count, 1);
```

Here are my mapping files.

AnnualReport class

```
<joined-subclass name="AnnualReport" extends="Report" table="AnnualReports" >  

<key column="ReportID"/>

<property name="MonthlySendDate" /> 

<bag name="MonthlyReports" lazy="true" inverse="true">
  <key column="ReportID" />
  <one-to-many class="MonthlyReport"/>
</bag>

<many-to-one name="Client" column="ClientID" not-null="true" /></joined-subclass>
```

MonthlyReport class

```
 <joined-subclass name="MonthlyReport" extends="Report" table="MonthlyReports">

<key column="ReportID"/>
<property name="SentDate" />

<many-to-one name="AnnualReport" class="AnnualReport" column="AnnualReportID"  not-null="true"/>

<bag name="MarketReports" cascade="all">
  <key column="MonthlyReportID" />
  <one-to-many class="MarketReport"/>
</bag>
```

Comment: Is it supposed to be many-to-many relationship?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your response Steve, I have managed to figure it out though. The foreign key mapping was incorrect.. below fixed the problem and now collection is loading.

```
<bag name="MonthlyReports" lazy="true" inverse="true">
  <key column="AnnualReportID" />
  <one-to-many class="MonthlyReport"/>
</bag>
```